# Using Point mode in a UserForm

Tags: excel, vba

I noticed that using a RefEdit control causes Excel to go into "Point" mode for selecting the appropriate range. (You see the "Ready" status change to "Point" and the current reference becomes animated in the current view).

My question is, is there any way to easily replicate this mode? I'm having issues because my form is not modal, and when coming back to it after using the RefEdit control, Excel just locks up (a known issue).
I suppose that merely setting Modal to true would fix it, but it would be nice to know a better way around this limitation.

Comment: I have already covered this before :) possible duplicate of [VBA Dialog box to select range in different workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125650/vba-dialog-box-to-select-range-in-different-workbook)

Comment: Whoops, didn't consider that question, since I'm not having troubles with selecting outside the workbook. ;)
Actually, thinking about it a little more, That issue applies here as well, since it's radically difficult to switch workbooks when a form is active.

Comment: and hence you use the form to switch workbooks :)

Comment: Yeah, but the problem I'm facing is not between differing books, but merely by keeping the form non-modal while using a RefEdit control. I'm just using one book, but want to have the ability to make changes etc, while still keeping the form available. 
The way I'm working around it now is to save the state of the form in a hidden sheet, and providing a button to re-show the form after the user closes it to continue working on the book. Not optimal, but it mostly works.

Comment: What about approaches where you don't unload your form, you just hide it then show it again modally as required? I.e. Make it modal for use of the problematic control, then when the control loses focus, hide the form and re-open it non-modal...

Comment: It's been a while since I had this issue. I think your idea might work to skirt the modal mode issue if the control supports subscribing to focus events. However, that wouldn't really solve the question of manually entering Point more through code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you use the application.inputbox you'll notice that the mode changes from Enter to Point when you click on the first cell in the range. You can test this out in the immediate window using the following code (where Type:=8 specifies a range):

```
?application.inputbox("Enter a range:","Range", Type:=8).address
```

If you change the selection, the input box display also changes.

Comment: I suppose this is a good workaround if you're okay with popping up another dialog for this. Of course, this would subvert the issue since it makes the InputBox modal instead of the Form so Excel doesn't do weird shenanigans on it. +1 for putting it in an answer.