# Cannot select range from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm writing a code to on one workbook which prompts the user to select where the data is in another workbook.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select Range", Title:="Range Select", Type:=8)
Dim ws As Worksheets: Set ws = Worksheets("Working")
```

The problem is I get the input dialog box but when I move to the other workbook to select the range it remains behind in the first workbook and so cannot select the range.

Comment: It is not possible to select a range from another workbook by using the `InputBox`. Instead you would need to create your own dialog box in order to accomplish this. There is a pretty nice solution to the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18126114/2119523

Answer (score 0):

To **Select** a range in a different workbook other than the active workbook, you must first activate the workbook and then activate or select the range .