# Capture cell value with TextBox in UserForm

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a UserForm which should be able to copy paste cells ideally. So firstly I would click the range I would want to copy, then activate the UserForm. The UserForm would have a combo box to choose which sheet I want to paste the data in, thereafter it would go to that sheet and user will click on the range or cell where he wants the data to be pasted.

I originally did an input box code to do this and it works perfectly, however when I do it in the UserForm it does not work as I am not able to incorporate the `Type:=8` code in the textbox.  Hence I would need some help on how can I enable my UserForm to paste cell data on the sheet, similarly to what I have done in `application.inputbox`.

This is the perfectly working code in the form of an input box:

```
Sub CopyPasteCumUpdateWithinSameSheet()


Dim rng As Range
Dim inp As Range

Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
Set inp = Selection
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
 On Error GoTo 0
    If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
inp.Copy

rng.Select

ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

'Cells(1,2).Font.ThemeColor =

End If

End Sub
```

This is the UserForm I have tried:

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error GoTo 0
    If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
inp.Copy

rng.Select

ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

CopyPasteUserform.Show vbModeless
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Sh.Name <> "Inputs" Then
            ComboBox1.AddItem Sh.Name
        End If
    Next

    ComboBox1.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
End Sub



Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ComboBox1.Text)
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With


End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()



Dim rng As Range
Dim inp As Range

Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
Set inp = Selection
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = TextBox.Value




End Sub
```

I tried incorporating the UserForm but all other functions stop responding apart from the RefEdit.

```
Dim Sh As Worksheet


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

CopyPasteUserform.Show vbModeless
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Sh.Name <> "Inputs" Then
            ComboBox1.AddItem Sh.Name
        End If
    Next

    ComboBox1.Style = fmStyleDropDownList

Dim rng As Range
Dim inp As Range

Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
Set inp = Selection
End Sub



Private Sub Combobox1_Change()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ComboBox1.Text)
        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Activate
    End With


End Sub

Private Sub RefEdit1_Change()
    Label1.Caption = ""

    If RefEdit1.Value <> "" Then _
    Label1.Caption = "[" & ComboBox1 & "]" & RefEdit1
    Dim rng As Range
Dim inp As Range


On Error Resume Next
Set rng = RefEdit1.Value
 On Error GoTo 0
    If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
inp.Copy

rng.Select

ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use RefEdit Control as shown [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125650/vba-dialog-box-to-select-range-in-different-workbook/18126114#18126114)?

Comment: I tried as per your suggesstion, it works in terms of ref edit but all other functions stop working, and does not fulfill my aim of copying and pasting data @SiddharthRout

Comment: I am not sure, how you are using it but from what I can see the above will work beautifully for you :)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt:/ all other buttons apart from the ref edit stops working. Any possible reasons? Really need help with this as it would save me lot of manual work! @SiddharthRout

Comment: Let me see... If I get some time today then I will try and post an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Your help would mean alot to me as it is the bulk of my assignment:) . Do tag me if you post it! @SiddharthRout

Comment: Would you be pasting in the same workbook?

Comment: yup same workbook within different sheets @SiddharthRout

Comment: Posted an answer. You may have to refresh the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the combobox to navigate to the sheets. That is the beauty of the `Refedit`

Is this what you are trying? I have not done any error handling. I am sure you can take care of that.

1. Create a userform and place 2 labels, 2 refedits and 1 commandbutton as shown below

   [image]
2. Next paste this code in the userform code area

**Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet

    If RefEdit1.Value <> "" And RefEdit2.Value <> "" Then
        Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Replace(Split(RefEdit1.Value, "!")(0), "'", ""))
        Set rngCopy = wsCopy.Range(Split(RefEdit1.Value, "!")(1))

        Set wsPaste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Replace(Split(RefEdit2.Value, "!")(0), "'", ""))
        Set rngPaste = wsPaste.Range(Split(RefEdit2.Value, "!")(1))

        rngCopy.Copy rngPaste
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select Input and Output range"
    End If
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

The data will be copied from `Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3` to `Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3`

**Followup From Comments**

> However the pastelink feature has been missed out in the userform. Is it possible to incorporate it?:) –  Niva 7 mins ago

Add a checkbox to the form as shown below

[image]

Use this code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet

    If RefEdit1.Value <> "" And RefEdit2.Value <> "" Then
        Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Replace(Split(RefEdit1.Value, "!")(0), "'", ""))
        Set rngCopy = wsCopy.Range(Split(RefEdit1.Value, "!")(1))

        Set wsPaste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Replace(Split(RefEdit2.Value, "!")(0), "'", ""))
        Set rngPaste = wsPaste.Range(Split(RefEdit2.Value, "!")(1))

        If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
            wsPaste.Activate
            rngPaste.Select
            rngCopy.Copy
            ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
        Else
            rngCopy.Copy rngPaste
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Please select Input and Output range"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly, just like what i wanted! However the pastelink feature has been missed out in the userform. Is it possible to incorporate it?:)

Comment: Also, i keep getting a subscript out of range when i copy paste from my database sheet. It runs with other sheets, except the database sheet. Why is that so? '

Comment: That is because you have a space in the name of the sheet. :) Let me update the code

Answer (score 2):

Description: Type:=8 will check that user input correct range name or not? In UserForm the TextBox not have this function. But we can detect this error when user click button. see my code.

No need to check when textbox is change, I delete code of textbox_change.

Replace below in your user form code area.

```
Option Explicit
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim inp As Range
Dim rng As Range

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = Me.TextBox1.Text
    'On Error Resume Next
    'If TypeName(Range(Me.TextBox1.Text)) <> "Range" Then
    '    MsgBox "Invalid range name!", vbCritical
    '    Exit Sub
    'Else
    '    inp.Copy
    '    rng.Select
    '    
    '    ActiveSheet.Paste Link:=True
    '    MsgBox "Copy and paste finish.", vbInformation
    'End If
    'On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If Sh.Name <> "Inputs" Then
        ComboBox1.AddItem Sh.Name
    End If
Next

ComboBox1.Style = fmStyleDropDownList
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ComboBox1.Text)
    .Visible = xlSheetVisible
    .Activate
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: the copy paste does not work. I want the user to be able to capture the range on the excel sheet and store it in the text box similar to the input box code!

Comment: Do you need to copy cell value to textbox on userform? I try to run your inputbox code but not see cell value in the input box.

Comment: Again, Your user input data in textbox and click button, then data in the textbox will paste to active cell in active sheet?

Comment: paste to the range of cell i click in the active sheet

Comment: So, you need only 1 line in the button1_click() that is ActiveCell.Value = Me.TextBox1.Text, I updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89569/discussion-between-adisak-anusornsrirung-and-niva).