# Excel VBA user copy/paste while running script.

Tags: vba, excel

i hope you guys can help me becasue i can't find the right answer to my question by searching online.

My Question: 
I want the user of my script get a message to copy and paste something and then go on with the script. it is ok if the user needs to click an ok button.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please elaborate the question as its not completely clear.

Comment: Why does your script need to ask the user to copy/paste?

Comment: I'm sorry, my english is very poor so i hope i do right: 
I have a small script that is unhiding a sheet (called "Data"), when the sheet is visible the user needs to copy from another (not defined) workbook a range to the  sheet  the script revealed and then go on with the rest of my script.

Comment: Why not copy and paste the something for the user.  That would be much easier.

Comment: because i don't know the workbook, sheet and range that needs to be copied.

Comment: You presumably have some attempt at this already? Why not post this out. It's okay not to have A+ english, but you still need to organize yours thoughts & your script...

Comment: Perhaps an appropriate use of `Application.InputBox` (which allows user to select ranges) could work. A more sophisticated approach would involve a modeless userform (where 2 or more event handlers would mimic the functionality of the single sub that you have in mind).

Comment: @eli That suggestion won't work. The still-running script disables copy and paste operations.

Comment: My suggestion about `Application.InputBox` can't be used directly, since experiments shows that it isn't possible to select a range on another workbook. There is a workaround involving allowing the user to select a workbook from a drop-down list of open workbooks, activating that workbook before the call to  `Application.InputBox` and then re-activating the original workbook.

Comment: So i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125650/vba-dialog-box-to-select-range-in-different-workbook
what pretty much needs to be done. Probably best to ask the User to give the Worksheetname/sheetname/range and then copy past it with script from the give input?

Comment: You should probably run the unhide script, then trigger the second part after doing something like this thread describes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818152/excel-vba-how-to-detect-if-something-was-pasted-in-a-worksheet

Comment: It is easier on the *programmer* to ask users to type the names. It is easier on the *user* if the programmer takes the time to create a userform capable of selecting ranges on a different workbook. If you are both the programmer and the user it is a matter of taste. If not -- whose time are you trying to optimize?