# Visual Basic For Application Related Question

Tags: excel, vba

How can i get the converted value from Celsius to Fahrenheit to show in a cell in the workbook of my choice?
Here is The Code for the problem:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Inches to Centimeters"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Feet to Meters"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Celsius to Fahrenheit"
    ' Add more conversion options as needed
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim inputValue As Double
    Dim conversionFactor As Double
    Dim convertedValue As Double
    Dim targetCell As Range
    
    inputValue = Val(TextBox1.Value)
    
    If IsNumeric(inputValue) Then
        Select Case ComboBox1.Value
            Case "Inches to Centimeters"
                conversionFactor = 2.54
            Case "Feet to Meters"
                conversionFactor = 0.3048
            Case "Celsius to Fahrenheit"
                convertedValue = (inputValue * 9 / 5) + 32
                MsgBox inputValue & " degrees Celsius converted to Fahrenheit is " & convertedValue
            ' Add more cases for other conversion options
        End Select
        
        convertedValue = inputValue * conversionFactor
        
        ' Prompt the user to select a cell to put the converted value
        ' Code Here
        
        
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid numeric value."
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim inputValue As Double
    Dim conversionFactor As Double
    Dim convertedValue As Double
    Dim targetCell As Range
    
    inputValue = Val(TextBox1.Value)
    
    If IsNumeric(inputValue) Then
        Select Case ComboBox1.Value
            Case "Inches to Centimeters"
                conversionFactor = 1 / 2.54
            Case "Feet to Meters"
                conversionFactor = 1 / 0.3048
            Case "Celsius to Fahrenheit"
                convertedValue = (inputValue - 32) * 5 / 9
                MsgBox inputValue & " degrees Fahrenheit converted to Celsius is " & convertedValue

            ' Add more cases for other conversion options
        End Select
        
        convertedValue = inputValue * conversionFactor
        
        ' Prompt the user to select a cell to put the converted value
        ' Code Here
        
        
        
    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid numeric value."
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to add a piece of code that us a input box where I can select a cell in the workbook to display the Converted Value. I have placed comment blocks in my code to know where to type the code in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18126114/1843468 This answer shows how to create a user dialog to let the user select a range. Does this help you?

Comment: Can you please type the code and give me it will rally helpful. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am on my mobile phone so I can't really code now. The code is in the linked answer. By the way, if you don't need to be able to select a different workbook, [`Application.InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) with `Type := 8` might be all you need.

Comment: Okay I'll check and try.

Comment: It's worth to immediately calculate the  `convertedValue` for every `Case` group and then process the result further.